# Question about formula for geometric sums

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-series

A long time ago when I was a high school students I've been taught the formula to sum the first $n$ terms of following geometric series
$$a_1,a_1q,a_1q^2,\ldots,a_1q^{n-1}$$
Is $S_n=\dfrac{a_1(1-q^n)}{1-q}$ . However when we asked the teacher why not writing it in easier form as $S_n=\dfrac{a_1(q^n-1)}{q-1}$, our teacher told us "because later we are going to learn about infinite sum of geometric series for $|q|<1$ and memorizing the formula in this way is easier to learn that" the formula for this case is $S_{\infty}=\dfrac{a_1}{1-q}$. And it is true it was better to learn the formula for $S_n$ as the former equation.

Here are my questions:

**First:** Is there another reason to encourage memorize formula as $S_n=\dfrac{a_1(1-q^n)}{1-q} ?$

**Second:** Now it is past about $5$ years since I learned about the formula for the first time. and I solved a lot of geometric series problem since that time( almost used the former formula every time). So can I use $S_n=\dfrac{a_1(q^n-1)}{q-1}$ in my head? doesn't that hurts? ( I want to use this because it is easier to calculate for example, $5^1+5^2+5^3+\ldots+5^{10}$ with $S=\dfrac{5(5^{10}-1)}{5-1}$ rather than having this unnecessary minus sign and see this as $S=\dfrac{5(1-5^{10})}{1-5}$

Comment: When $q>1$, it is indeed a lot more natural (especially when doing mental calculations) to use $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$.

Comment: I learned it when I was trying to solve math contest problems in school and it was taught as $\frac{a^{k+1}-1}{a-1}$

Comment: For your first question, there are a number of situations, where the finite formula is useful.  Your 2nd question  focuses on one of them, which may be routinely arrived at by starting with the formula in the 1st question, and multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $(-1)$.  Therefore, there is no need to memorize two formulas.  ...see next comment

Comment: Further, consider the justification of the formula for $S_{\infty} ~:~ |q| < 1,~$ which is based on starting with the formula for $S_n$ and then considering the **error term** $\frac{a_1 q^n}{1 - q}.$ It is immediate that $|q| < 1 \implies$ that this error term goes to zero, as $n \to \infty$.